# Facebook Integration IN PHP (without opening face book page)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing the web service for mobile phone(Like ios, adnroid etc). I dont have login/signup through facebook in my App. But i want to share the data from my App to facebook (and twitter ) as a post. For this, i dont want to redirect user to facebook to enter their credentials on facebook and then share the data. My requirement is get only Username and password from the user save it in DB and call the FB API from my webservice which will check for the authentication of the user credentials (Facebook ) and if correct then it will psot the data / message to user FB wall. I am trying with php for this , but all the libraries and codes available, are going for FB login window.

I know that offline facebook access is removed, but still want to go for it.

Please, one guide me for this. Any code for php or code for mobile (Iphone and Android) will work

Answer (score 1):

You can´t use the api with only username and password, that would be a major security problem. If someone hacks your database > access to all Facebook accounts.

That being said, you don´t need to authorize a user for sharing, the Facebook docs offer a lot of information about that topic: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing

You can just use the native share dialogs. For posting without a dialog, you would need to do a lot more things:

- Authorize the user with the publish_actions permission
- Go through a review process on Facebook with that permission
- Use /me/feed to post: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed

And keep in mind that the message parameter must be 100% user generated, see platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> 2.3 Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments,
>   and captions.

A generated message will not get you through the review process.